# regex validation for keyboard special character- grails

Tags: regex, grails, groovy

i am very new to this Grails.
I know there are ways in it to stop the input with specific character using constraints and matches for the field.

I am using it to stop the user from entering any special character from the keyboard

I have used

```
matches:/^[^$@#*^%~]*$/
```

it checks that field does not have *^%$#@~, and it works fine for this set of characters but I also want to restrict the user from adding +-(}/\|{[?]!<>~;',=&_.:" (in short all the special symbols on keyboard). And using only this constraints. I have tried putting them in this regular expression pattern but it is still allowing it or if does allow than it not showing in error message which were entered in the field.

> For ex:- If I have entered **(+)&^** than error message is shown only as "Please do not enter ^." but I want, "Please do not enter (+)&^."

Please let me know if anyone knows.

Please also note that I am required to use only Grails/Groovy support no JS/JQuery.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Below regex will prevent from entering any character other than alphanumeric, and also at least one character. If you do not want minimum one character, then replace `+` with `*`

```
/^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

Comment: `/^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$/` will prevent from entering any character that IS alphanumeric. I believe that you meant `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/` which matches only alphanumeric characters.

Comment: hi @Xeon, the regex is correct. `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` means the characters which are not belongs to a-z and 0-9. The `^` sign simply inverted the meaning.

Comment: `matches:/^[^$@#*^%~]*$/` - so OP wants regexp that **matches valid text** and not check if there is any not alphanumerical character in provided text. The regexps are correct but they stand for opposite purpose. The above regex will match only nonalpha from start to end of the line so it doesn't match this: `a#$@$a` but only `@#$`. If you want to inverse condition i.e. "if matches regexp -> it's not valid" this is wrong regexp because `a@#$a` won't match which should be invalid. If you use `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/`: `a@#$a` (doesn't match -> invalid), `asdf` (matches -> valid)

Comment: Xeon is correct... @SabujHassan what you gave as answer is an idea which i worked on to fix the problem and I did ended up having the problem Xeon showed....But Still looking into it for for as it is a solution or not